# VS 2015 saying remote debugger is required for local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, iis

I am running an MVC 5 app using web api, Visual Studio 2015, .net 4.6.1 and local IIS 8 (Windows 10).  For some reason when I try to start debugging, it says it cannot start because the remote debugger is not running.  Did something change in requiring this to be running for a local IIS site?  I can manually attach to a process and start debugging that way but for whatever reason pressing F5 to start debugging won't work.  Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Down voting by itself isn't helpful, please include comments too.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of reasons can cause issues like this.
Take a look here for troubleshooting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx I actually checked mine VS 2015 setup running on Windows 2012 R2, and I can debug my Web Application running on local IIS no problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help but still couldn't get this working properly.  Seems to only be an issue with ASP.NET apps.  I don't have issues trying to debug other .NET apps (console, Windows Universal, etc).  It's really weird.  I might just try reinstalling Visual Studio (Community) 2015 to see if it helps.  At this point it's worth a shot.

Comment: @PeterZimmerman Just a shot, but do you run Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: I did, otherwise my project which is setup for my local IIS won't load.